# how to set Facebook developer account to make app get permission to post something

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to add Facebook sharing function to my iOS app.I want people can post their feeling about my app on Facebook.But it failed and Xcode show the error "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".I'm sure my code is right, because I use other people's Facebook app secrete to try and it works well. So I think the problem is in my Facebook developer account's setting about my app.
My Facebook app is in developing mode.

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Do you have a valid Facebook account in the device? or simulator?. You should also make sure the app is set up properly  in the Facebook developer portal.

Comment: I believe you are missing something when initialising the Facebook API on your code. Can you post some codes on how to get the permission and etc?

Comment: @eharo2 Yes,I use a test account to log in Facebook on my iPhone.I think maybe my app's permission setting is wrong in Facebook developer portal.But I didn't find where to set it.

Comment: @Ricky I didn't use Facebook's official SDK.I use shareSDK which combine multiple social platform's SDK.The shareSDK's demo project works well, But when I change the app secret and app id to mine, it shows the error.So I think the problem is in my Facebook developer account's setting.

Comment: I have added my answer below on how to add the publish_actions on your Facebook App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete my app on Facebook and add it again ,then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% confirm that the problem is not on your app side, this is what you can do.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUAPPID/review-status/ under **Submit Items for Approval** Click the button "**Start a Submission**". Then Tick **publish_actions** and click "**Add Items**". You will see more instruction on screen and also remember to read the review guidelines. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

[image]

Comment: I will use this method as my last plan. I think it should work in developing mode before I submit review. So I want to do some setting before submit review.

Comment: The review is Unapproved.The reviewer said "I tested your app on the iOS simulator and while I was able to login to Facebook successfully, the content that I wanted to share onto my Facebook wall was never published."