# Not able to sharing feed to facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios7

In my application i'm not able to sharing feed to facebook. I getting **(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action** error.
my code is:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"]];

    asiRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [asiRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

     NSString *link =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=sf-OU6rULoyBoAOk8YHADg"];

    //[asiRequest setPostValue:fbtextView.text forKey:@"message"];
    [asiRequest setPostValue:link forKey:@"link"];
    [asiRequest setPostValue:acessToken  forKey:@"access_token"];
    [asiRequest setPostValue:@"testing" forKey:@"name"];
    [asiRequest setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/wonup-akiajjcm7taqsdtarnda/WonUp06-03-2014-12-14-PM.jpeg"] forKey:@"picture"];

    [asiRequest setDelegate:self];
    [asiRequest startAsynchronous];
});
```

and also i'm using FBWebDialog code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params1;

params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"testing", @"name",@"356993987780240",@"app_id",acessToken,@"access_token",link,@"link", nil];

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:params1 handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
     {
         // NSLog(@"result ======%@",resultURL);
         if (error)
         {
             //  NSLog(@"error ======%@",error);
         }
         else
         {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
             {
                 // NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             }
             else
             {
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"])
                 {
                     // NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
                     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WonUp" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are successfully Posted"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                         [alertView show];

                     });

                 }
             }
         }
     }];

});
```

it's killing my time. Please give me your suggestions and code.  Thanks in advance

Comment: This person had the same problem, deleted the app and put it on again and it worked... check this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576960/how-to-set-facebook-developer-account-to-make-app-get-permission-to-post-somethi)

Comment: @Michael now i'm getting "Invalid parameter" error

Comment: Please update your post with the error log